# Is it possible to connect remote Oracle APEX to ATP with ORDS?

Tags: oracle-call-interface, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have Oracle Apex which currently is installed on OVH Cloud Server and its connected to Amazon AWS with ORDS. Is it possible to be connected to Autonomous Databases and how? I have already try to make connection with ORDS as the same way as i connect it to amazon aws ,but i receive error: access denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/atp-cloud/atpug/ords-intro.html#GUID-60B1BC79-CF7D-4BBA-822F-74FAF29DCC7A) it is currently not possible to connect a customer-managed ORDS application to Autonomous Transaction Processing.

Answer (score 0):

That has changed. You can now host your own ORDS instance with an Autonomous Database. I've summarised how you can get this done:
https://fuzziebrain.com/content/id/2004/

Better late than never. HTH. :-)